# How to mock react leaflet map events in jest

Tags: react-hooks, react-leaflet, babel-jest

I have below code snippet which is not covered in jest test coverage. Can someone please help to cover those lines in jest test.

```
const map = useMap();

const locationClick(): void => { map.locate().on("location found", function (e) {

setP(e.lating); map.flyTo(e.lating, 10.3);

const radius = e.accuracy;

map.setzoom (14.3);

const circle L.circle(e.lating, radius); circle.addTo(map); =

});

};
```

Comment: Hi, could you post the component file if possible? It would be easier to know how the map code is being used. If you have written tests for the component, add those as well.

Comment: @ParthTomar I am calling locationClick() function inside an use effect